# Changing the post date and time with function

Tags: posts, functions, date

What function can be used to update a post's post date and time to the current date & time?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Call `wp_update_post()` with a special value for `'post_date'` and `'post_date_gmt'`:

```
$time = current_time('mysql');

wp_update_post(
    array (
        'ID'            => 123, // ID of the post to update
        'post_date'     => $time,
        'post_date_gmt' => get_gmt_from_date( $time )
    )
);
```

Comment: This answer is still valid in 2021.

Comment: Super helpful and simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The selected answer is perfect for modifying the "publish date", but in my case I wanted to change the "last modified" date (`post_modified` and `post_modified_gmt` in the db).  The following is sufficient for that:

```php
wp_update_post( [ 'ID' => $id ] );
```